# About global variables

Tags: c++, global-variables

Consider two code snippets as below:

Case I:

```
class A {
    int globalOrLocal;
    funcA1() {…}
    funcA2() {…}
}
```

Case II:

```
int globalOrLocal;
class B {
    funcB1() {…}
    funcB2() {…}
}
```

Out of Case I and Case II above, which declaration of variable `globalOrLocal` can be called global?  I think both, since they are defined outside all the functions due to which this variable would be stored on the heap.  But I am not sure.  Online resources give trivial examples without any involvement of classes.  Could someone please help solve my doubt?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried accessing `globalOrLocal` from `main` in both cases? What happens? If it's truly global, you should be able to access it with no problem, right?

Comment: In both cases both functions can access the variable

Comment: Only the second one is global.

Comment: @scohe001, I don't know what problem you are talking about.  I can access it in both the functions, as Turan has pointed out.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope  This lays it out pretty thoroughly.  Class scope and global scope are two different levels.

Comment: @hegel5000, thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @P.K. [Are you sure?](https://ideone.com/isAmnE)

Comment: @scohe001, [yes, I am](https://ideone.com/LVjQPi).  If you are more explicit, then maybe it might help.

Comment: @P.K. you're declaring a new `globalOrLocal` in the scope of `main`. Even if you **had** declared a `globalOrLocal` as global, the code you're using there would create a new variable with the same name in `main` that would overshadow the global definition. [Here's a quick example](https://ideone.com/MDl9k8).

Comment: @scohe001, got your point.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case I `globalOrLocal` is not a global variable. It is a private member variable of `class A`. An instance of it will be constructed for each instance of `A` that you construct and will be destroyed along with `A` when it is destroyed.

In Case II you (potentially) have a global variable. Depends on whether there is an anonymous namespace wrapping it or another class holding it and class `A` as members/nested class.